Why type mismatch expm crate?
So I need to compute the exponential function, where the exponent is a Matrix. Since I am using the ndarray crate, and didn't find an implementation for, e.g., exp(H), where H is the matrix.
I stumbled upon the expm crate.
However I wasn't able to get it to work. I always get the error:
error[E0308]: arguments to this function are incorrect
    --> src/main.rs:30:5
     |
30   |     expm(&eye, &mut b);
     |     ^^^^
     |
note: expected `&ArrayBase<_, Dim<[usize; 2]>>`, found `&ArrayBase<OwnedRepr<_>, Dim<...>>`
    --> src/main.rs:30:10
     |
30   |     expm(&eye, &mut b);
     |          ^^^^
     = note: `ArrayBase<OwnedRepr<_>, Dim<...>>` and `ArrayBase<_, Dim<[usize; 2]>>` have similar names, but are actually distinct types
note: `ArrayBase<OwnedRepr<_>, Dim<...>>` is defined in crate `ndarray`
    --> C:\Users\...\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\ndarray-0.15.6\src\lib.rs:1268:1
     |
1268 | pub struct ArrayBase<S, D>
     | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: `ArrayBase<_, Dim<[usize; 2]>>` is defined in crate `ndarray`
    --> C:\Users\...\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\ndarray-0.12.1\src\lib.rs:1026:1
     |
1026 | pub struct ArrayBase<S, D>
     | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
     = note: perhaps two different versions of crate `ndarray` are being used?
note: expected `&mut ArrayBase<_, Dim<[usize; 2]>>`, found `&mut ArrayBase<OwnedRepr<f64>, ...>`
    --> src/main.rs:30:16
     |
30   |     expm(&eye, &mut b);
     |                ^^^^^^
     = note: `ArrayBase<OwnedRepr<f64>, Dim<...>>` and `ArrayBase<_, Dim<[usize; 2]>>` have similar names, but are actually distinct types
note: `ArrayBase<OwnedRepr<f64>, Dim<...>>` is defined in crate `ndarray`
    --> C:\Users\...\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\ndarray-0.15.6\src\lib.rs:1268:1
     |
1268 | pub struct ArrayBase<S, D>
     | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: `ArrayBase<_, Dim<[usize; 2]>>` is defined in crate `ndarray`
    --> C:\Users\...\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\ndarray-0.12.1\src\lib.rs:1026:1
     |
1026 | pub struct ArrayBase<S, D>
     | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
     = note: perhaps two different versions of crate `ndarray` are being used?
note: function defined here
    --> C:\Users\...\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\expm-0.1.1\src\lib.rs:706:8
     |
706  | pub fn expm<S1, S2>(a: &ArrayBase<S1, Ix2>, b: &mut ArrayBase<S2, Ix2>)
     |        ^^^^

My code:

use ndarray::*;
use ndarray_rand::rand_distr::num_traits::Pow;

extern crate openblas_src;


fn main() {

    let d: usize =   3;

    let eye: AArrayBase<ndarray::OwnedRepr<f64>, Dim<[usize; 2]>>  = Array::eye(d);
    let mut b: ArrayBase<ndarray::OwnedRepr<f64>, Dim<[usize; 2]>> = Array::eye(d);

    expm::expm(&eye, &mut b);
 

}

My .toml:
[package]
name = "hello_world"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"


[dependencies]
meshgridrs = "0.1.1"
ndarray = "0.15.6"
ndarray-rand = "0.14"
ndarray-stats = "0.4"
rand = "0.8"
plotly = "0.7.0"
nalgebra = "0.33.0"
expm = "0.1.1"
openblas-src = { version = "0.9", features = ["system"] }

I am on a windows system and use vscode for development. I installed/compiled openblas-src, following the crate discription.
I followed the example on expm the crate page. Yet it doesn't work. Since I am fairly new to rust, my inexperience could be the cause of it.
What am I doing wrong here?

Please put the full error from cargo check (not your IDE), formatted as code.

Please include your dependencies and versions

I hope I updated everything to your requests.

Do you actually need so many deps for the snippet? Please provide a Minimal Reproducible Example. After you trim down dependencies, put here the output of cargo tree.

expm depends on the outdated and incompatible ndarray ^0.12 so you can't use it with types from ndarray ^0.15 downgrade your ndarray dependency (or submit an update to expm / swith away from it)

So the version really was the problem. I tested it with various  versions. It only works up to 0.12. Now I only have a linking error remaining with the lapack package.

@ChayimFriedman Thank you for pointing me to cargo tree. Just learned something new!
